# Python 3.3 Bug? Appending a list to a list:

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

I'm trying to make code that can build some sort of editable world map in the form of a 2D array:

```
class map(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width

        self.__grid = []
        row = []
        for num in range(0, self.__width):
            row.append(".")
        for num in range(0, self.__height):
            self.__grid.append(row)
        print(self.__grid)

    def drawCell(self, X, Y, symbol):
        self.__grid[Y-1][X-1] = symbol
        print(self.__grid)

world = map(6, 4)
world.drawCell(3, 2, "0")
```

When I run this, instead of editing cell (3, 2) it seems to do the 3rd cell in every row.
Bizarrely, when I change **init**() to this...

```
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width

        self.__grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

...so that **init** skips the construction of the grid, it works perfectly! It looks like it's appending the variable 'row' instead of the value it contains and so it edits every instance of 'row'.

Of course, this solution above doesn't allow for varying map-size. So my question is: is there a non-redundant way around this?

Edit: You don't need to explain why it's happening, I already sort of explain it. I imagined when I made this that it appended the value, not the variable containing it.

Comment: Have you considered using NumPy?

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Rob, that blew my mind. I've been taught a simple understanding of variables by my teacher it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid generation is wrong.

```
row = []
for num in range(0, self.__width):
    row.append(".")
for num in range(0, self.__height):
    self.__grid.append(row)
```

You are appending the same (in the sense that it is really the same, multiple references of the same list) row each time (note that `row` was defined only once!). Change this to that:

```
for num in range(0, self.__height):
    row = []
    for num2 in range(0, self.__width):
        row.append(".")
    self.__grid.append(row)
```

As you can see this is not a bug in Python. :)

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it should've looked like a nested for-loop but I didn't think it mattered.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating **one** list, then append that same list to `self.__grid` `self.__height` times.

Append copies instead:

```
for num in range(0, self.__height):
    self.__grid.append(row[:])
```

Or better still, generate the whole grid with a generator expression:

```
self.__grid = [['.'] * self.__width for _ in self.__height]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think freakish's solution is a bit cleaner, but this has taught me a useful python trick around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you do `self.__grid.append(row)` a bunch of times, it appends a reference to the same list object every time, so when you edit a reference to one of them, you're editing the object behind all the references.

This will do what you want:

```
    self.__grid = []
    for num in range(0, self.__height):
        row = []
        for num in range(0, self.__width):
            row.append(".")
        self.__grid.append(row)
```

But it's much more compact if you use list comprehensions:

```
self.__grid = [['.' for a in range(self.__width)] for b in range(self.__height)]
```

That makes each row a reference to a separate list object.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you weren't building *(height)* different rows, you were building one row list and appending it to `self.__grid` *(height)* times.  This means that changing one row would change all of the other rows, since all elements of `self.__grid` referenced the same list object.

In your original code you could fix this by altering this line:

```
self.__grid.append(row)
```

To make a copy of the template row instead:

```
self.__grid.append(list(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you do:

```
self.__grid.append(row)
```

in the first example you are appending the same `row` object to every row. If you want to avoid this you can do:

```
self.__grid.append(row[:])
```

to create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Simple NumPy Implementation :D

```
import numpy as np  

world = np.ones(shape = (6,4)).astype(str) #YourGrid
world[3,2] = "0" #DrawCell

print world
```

Yields:

```
[['1.0' '1.0' '1.0' '1.0']
 ['1.0' '1.0' '1.0' '1.0']
 ['1.0' '1.0' '1.0' '1.0']
 ['1.0' '1.0' '0' '1.0']
 ['1.0' '1.0' '1.0' '1.0']
 ['1.0' '1.0' '1.0' '1.0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers but I'd also mention that it can be shortened to

```
self.__grid = [['.'] * self.__height for i in range(self.__width)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a list in python is an *object*, and when you assign a list/object to a variable you are simply passing a pointer to it. Same goes for when you are appending a list to another list. So in this case you end up appending the pointer to the same object multiple times (which is why when you edit one you edit all).

You have to either recreate multiple instances (look up list comprehension, one succinct way to initialize multi-dimensional lists), or copy the list as you append them.